# React Redux typescript throwing error: Type is not assignable to type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm changing my React App to TS and I'm getting this error, and I'm not sure why. Will appreciate any help.

This is my "mapStateToProps" code:

```
function mapStateToProps(state: AppState): MapStateToProps{
   const cost = state.costReducer;
      return { 
         sLoading: cost.get("loading")
```

> The error happens here:
>
> Type 'boolean | ICost' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

```
        }
      }
```

These are the related types:

```
export type MapStateToProps = {
  sLoading: boolean
}
```

This is The reducer:

```
type InitialState = {
    loading: boolean,
    data: ICost
 }
let defaultState: InitialState = {
      loading: false,
      data: {
        optionOne: null,
        optionTwo: null
   }
};
export default function (state = Map(defaultState), action: AppActions){
    switch (action.type) {
      case costActionsTypes.COST_FETCH_DATA_STARTED:
        return state.set("loading", true);
      case costActionsTypes.COST_FETCH_DATA_SUCCEEDED:
        return state.set("loading", false);
     );
     case costActionsTypes.COST_FETCH_DATA_FAILED:
        return state.set("loading", false);
  default:
    return state;
 }
}
```

Will appreciate any suggestion

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are having errors is because of this weird and unnecessary use of `Map`.  The type `boolean | ICost` in your error means that it doesn't know if `cost.get("loading")` is getting the `boolean` from `loading` of the `ICost` from `data`.

If `Map` here refers to the built-in `Map` object then your reducer doesn't even compile because `Map(defaultState)` is nonsense.  If `Map` is some sort of custom utility, then you would need to define `get` as a generic that returns the value of the specific key that it was called with rather than a union of all possible values.

Here's a more standard redux setup.

```
function mapStateToProps(state: AppState) {
  return { 
    isLoading: state.costReducer.loading 
  }
}
```

```
export default function ( state: InitialState = defaultState, action: AppActions ) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case costActionsTypes.COST_FETCH_DATA_STARTED:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case costActionsTypes.COST_FETCH_DATA_SUCCEEDED:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false
      };
    case costActionsTypes.COST_FETCH_DATA_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```